# How to create Notifications in Salesforce Lightning via Process Builder

Tags: lightning, tasks, notification

How do I create Notifications in Salesforce Lightning?

[image]

For example, how would I get a Task/Reminder created via Process Builder to appear as a Notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the Task notification by following the below steps:-

1. From Setup, select Object Manager.
2. Click Task.
3. Open an existing task layout or create one.
4. Add the Reminder Set field to your Task Detail section of our org’s
   Task page layouts.
5. Deselect Show simpler New Task form on mobile on the Activity
   Settings page. The simpler New Task form doesn’t include the options for creating task notifications.
6. Push notifications and reminders in the notification tray aren’t
   supported in the Salesforce app. While reps can set and change
   notification settings in the Salesforce app, they don’t receive
   notifications in it.

> For your reps to receive reminders, you must enable Universal
>   Notification Service (UNS). UNS is used for notifications in the
>   Lightning Experience notification bell and is enabled by default.

Refrence:- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=tasks_enable_task_notifications.htm&type=0

Comment: Thanks. Would these instructions apply to Tasks created by Process Builder?